# Loading the breqn package changes appearance of inline maths

Tags: amsmath, inline, breqn

Consider this MWE. Why when I load the package `breqn` does the appearance of the `\frac{}{}` change?

**With `breqn` loaded**

[image]

**Without `breqn`**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
$\frac{1}{\mathbf{A}\boldsymbol{B}}$ $\mathbf{A}\boldsymbol{B}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load also `bm`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

$\frac{1}{\mathbf{A}\boldsymbol{B}}$ $\mathbf{A}\boldsymbol{B}$

\end{document}
```

You can also use the shorter `\bm` instead of `\boldsymbol`.

[image]